# MVC сложные View Models

Tags: c#, mvc

Не могу победить ошибку при запуске View RequestCreate.cshtml:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'SDS.WebUI.Models.RequestEditViewModel', but this dictionary requires
>   a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SDS.WebUI.Models.RequestDetailListViewModel]'.

Что не так?

Имеется:

**View Models:**

```
public class RequestEditViewModel  
{  
     public int RequestID { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual IEnumerable<RequestDetailListViewModel> RequestDetails { get; set; }

}

public class RequestDetailListViewModel
{

        [Key]
        public int RequestDetailID { get; set; }

        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RequestID")]
        public virtual Request Request { get; set; }

        public string DetailName { get; set; }
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult RequestCreate()
{
    RequestEditViewModel mVm = new RequestEditViewModel {};

    return View(mVm);
}
```

**Views:**

*RequestCreate.cshtml*

```
@model SDS.WebUI.Models.RequestEditViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    .....

     Html.Partial("RequestDetailPartialView");

     //Html.Partial("RequestDetailPartialView",   @Model.RequestDetails.AsEnumerable());
     //Html.RenderPartial("RequestDetailPartialView", null);
}
```

*RequestDetailPartialView.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<SDS.WebUI.Models.RequestDetailListViewModel>
@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridRequestDetail";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "RequestDetailID";
        .....
        settings.Columns.Add("RequestDetailID");
        settings.Columns.Add("DetailName");

   });
}

@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Comment: `Html.Partial("RequestDetailPartialView",   @Model.RequestDetails);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Html.Partial("RequestDetailPartialView");
> ```

```
Html.Partial("RequestDetailPartialView", Model.RequestDetails);
```